# Plotting parallel coordinates in pandas/python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, parallel-coordinates

I am trying to use pandas in python to plot the following higher-dimensional data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/34nbR.jpg

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
from pandas.tools.plotting import parallel_coordinates

data = pandas.read_csv('ParaCoords.csv')
parallel_coordinates(data,'Name')
```

The code fails to plot the data, and the Traceback error ends with:

```
Keyerror: 'Name'
```

What is the second argument in parallel_coordinates supposed to say/do?
How can I successfully plot the data?

Comment: I think the second argument must be the name of the column you want to use for your plot. That why in `iris.data` they use 'Name'.

Comment: Any string I use in the second argument's position (i.e. 'column-name') results in a function error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is supposed to be the column name that defines `class`.  Think `['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'cat', 'dog']`.

In the [example online](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#parallel-coordinates) they use `'Name'` as the second argument because that is a column defining names of iris's

#### Doc

> ```
> Signature: parallel_coordinates(*args, **kwargs)
> Docstring:
> Parallel coordinates plotting.
>
> Parameters
> ----------
> frame: DataFrame
> class_column: str
>     Column name containing class names
> cols: list, optional
>     A list of column names to use
> ax: matplotlib.axis, optional
>     matplotlib axis object
> color: list or tuple, optional
>     Colors to use for the different classes
> use_columns: bool, optional
>     If true, columns will be used as xticks
> xticks: list or tuple, optional
>     A list of values to use for xticks
> colormap: str or matplotlib colormap, default None
>     Colormap to use for line colors.
> axvlines: bool, optional
>     If true, vertical lines will be added at each xtick
> axvlines_kwds: keywords, optional
>     Options to be passed to axvline method for vertical lines
> kwds: keywords
>     Options to pass to matplotlib plotting method
> ```

Comment: I see! So, y is my dependent variable; and x1, x2, x3, and x4 are my independent variables. The second argument should be 'y'; or it could be 'x1', 'x2', etc.

Comment: hi! Is there any options for customising the legend of parallel_coordinates plot?

Comment: @cucurbit you can customize it the same way you would for any `matplotlib` plot.  Essentially, assign the return value of the plot to a variable.  It will be an `axes` object.  Then manipulate from there.  You'll want to search for **matplotlib legend**

Answer (score 1):

The iris.data file that you [download from UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/) does not have headers.  To make the pandas example work, you have to assign the headers explicitly as column names:

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import parallel_coordinates
# The iris.data file from UCI does not have headers,
# so we have to assign the column names explicitly.
data = pd.read_csv("data-iris-for-pandas/iris.data")
data.columns=["x1","x2","x3","x4","Name"]
plt.figure()
parallel_coordinates(data,"Name")
```

[image: Pandas Parallel Coordinates Example]

Basically, the pandas documentation is incomplete.  Someone put the column names into the dataframe without letting us know.